# Find object button In Xamarin IOS

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am new in IOS and using websync tech to sync data and keep update price button, but how can I find the object button in IOS? In Android it can use findbyId function, Isn't got any solution? I using this setValueForKey function but always get error.

```
Name: NSUnknownKeyException Reason: [<SA_IOS_MatchScreen 0x7fab255c4730> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key TG01.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use **ViewWithTag**! Just remember set tag value.
Then you can use tag to find your button.
I tried it and it works!
*** Don't set tag = 0 because it's default value is 0;**

```
UIButton btn1 = this.View.ViewWithTag(1) as UIButton;
btn1.Enabled = false;
btn1.SetTitle("Change!",UIControlState.Normal);
```

Comment: ViewWithTag is a horrible approach. You should create an outlet for your button and give it a proper name.

Comment: Actually this is my first time to use ViewWitTag.  There is another way to find your button. You can set it's name in storyboard.Then you can use that name like id!